# Can I use a (business process) lane in a sequence diagram in enterprise architect?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, bpmn, sequence-diagram

In Enterprise Architect I have represented one of our systems as a lane on a BPMN diagram.
I would like to reuse that system in various UML sequence diagrams, however when I add the system to a SD it shows as a lane rather than a Lifeline.
Any idea how to approach that?

Comment: Just drag it from the browser to any diagram

Comment: i did drag it. it remains a lane. i expect it to become a Lifeline

Comment: A lifeline will only appear in a SD. Oh, you said it in the title, but not in the text...

Comment: Are you using BPMN? UML has only Partition. BPMN has Pool and Lane.

Comment: yes, i use bpmn

Comment: @tommer, I've heavily reworded your question. Please check if that is aligned with your intention and accept/reject the changes accordingly.

Comment: looks good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you talk about BPMN, the [specs](https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0.1/PDF) say on p. 111

> A Pool acts as the container for the Sequence Flows

Lanes are just sub-partitions of pools.

So, it is not an object that has behavior but only surrounds a couple of behaviors.

You would need to create single SDs showing the behavior of actitivities inside a lane. Question is: why use SDs which are meant for technical description if you already described the communication on a business process level?

Comment: good point: the LifeLine in a sequence diagram is typically part of the system-that-is-a-lane-in-the-business-process